# How does this linear algebra definition describe an ellipsoid?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ellipsoids

Let $S^n$ define a  symmetric matrix, $S=\{B: B=B^T\}$. We associate with each $A\in S^n_{++}$ an ellipsoid centered at the origin given by:
\begin{align}
\epsilon_A = \{x : x^T A^{-1}x\leq 1\}.
\end{align}

I am kinda a novice at linear algebra, so I am confused and don't really understand why the point $x$ is being multiplied twice by the inverse of $A$. Could anybody please elaborate on the notation here and how this actually creates an ellipsoid?

**EDIT:**
Looking at the $n=2$ case,
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    a && c\\
    c && b
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow 
A^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    b/(ab-c^2) && -c/(ab-c^2)\\
    -c/(ab-c^2) && a/(ab-c^2)
\end{bmatrix}\\
x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    x\\
    y
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
    x,y
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    b/(ab-c^2) && -c/(ab-c^2)\\
    -c/(ab-c^2) && a/(ab-c^2)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    x\\
    y
\end{bmatrix}\\
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    x,y
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    xb/(ab-c^2)-yc/(ab-c^2)\\
ya/(ab-c^2)-xc/(ab-c^2)
\end{bmatrix}\\
= \frac{bx^2+ay^2-c(x+y)}{ab-c^2}\leq1\\
\Rightarrow bx^2 + ay^2 \leq (ab-c^2)+c(x+y)\\
\Rightarrow bx^2 + ay^2 - c(x+y)\leq -c^2+ab
$$
Setting $c=0$ we get the equation for an ellipse:
$$
bx^2 + ay^2 \leq ab\\
\Rightarrow \frac{ax^2}{b} + \frac{by^2}{a} \leq 1
$$

Comment: In two or three dimensions, do you know the equation for an ellipse or an ellipsoid?  (In the simplest case the axes of the ellipse are aligned with the x, y, z axes.)  That equation involves $x^{2}$, $y^{2}$, and (in the 3-d case), $z^{2}$.

Comment: My suggestion is to expand the product in the n=2 case. If after that you are still lost, post your results and I will be glad to help you again

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thanks that actually helps, but because in the equation above $x^TA^{-1}x\leq 1$ does that mean that the ellipsoid is contained within the unit circle?

Comment: @FormerMath, I tried to do it in my question, but it didnt turn out the way I thought it would. Did I make a mistake somewhere or is this correct?

Comment: @FormerMath, I see a mistake in my inverse matrix

Comment: @FormerMath, I made the change but it did not change much

Comment: Try with $S$ diagonal first.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, I can see with the diagonal, by setting $c=0$ that its an ellipse! Thank you, what does this mean about the $c$ value? Is it still an ellipse if $c!=0$?

Comment: Yes, for $c=0$ it's an ellipse, whose symmetry axes are the $x$- and the $y$-axid. Now in the general case, it's still an ellipse (graph it with a graphing program) but "rotated". Secretly there's a coordinate change involved. Now this is the core of copper.hat's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ can be written as $A=U \Lambda U^T$ where $U$ is orthogonal and $\Lambda$ diagonal.

Note that $\epsilon_\Lambda = \{ y | \sum_k {1 \over \lambda_k} y_k^2  \le 1 \}$ and
so $\epsilon_A = U \epsilon_\Lambda$ (that is, a rotation of the $\Lambda$ ellipsoid).